# Error connecting Derby Database in Netbeans: Invalid attribute syntax

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

I'm getting error when trying to connect to Derby Database in netbeans.
Below is the method where the error occurs.

```
 public int myConnect() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | java.lang.InstantiationException | java.lang.IllegalAccessException e) {
        }

        String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample;create=true;user=app;password=app; ";



        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into students(name,email) values(?,?)");

        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.setString(2, email);

        int test = ps.executeUpdate();

        if (test == 1) {
            return test;
        } 

    }
```

This is the error **org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Invalid attribute syntax: ;create=true;user=app;password=app;** .

The username and password are correct too.
Any help is appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Try removing the trailing whitespace and semicolon

Comment: Thank you cricket_007.It worked by removing only the trailing whitespace.

Comment: Failing due to trailing whitespace, and with such a confusing message, seems like a flaw in Derby, to me. You could benefit the Derby community by reporting this as a bug in the Derby bug tracker: http://db.apache.org/derby/DerbyBugGuidelines.html